# UPSERT - INSERT ... ON CONFLICT fails with a function based index as 'lower()' unique constraint

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint, lowercase, upsert

I have a database table with a `code` column that uses a lowercase index to prevent code values that only differ in case (e.g. 'XYZ' = 'xYZ' = 'xyz'). The typical way in Postgresql is to create a function based index, like this: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX mytable_lower_code_idx ON mytable (lower(code))`.

Now I have a case where I need upsert behaviour on that column:

```
-- first insert
INSERT INTO mytable (code) VALUES ('abcd');

-- second insert, with upsert behaviour
INSERT INTO mytable (code) VALUES ('Abcd')
  ON CONFLICT (code) DO UPDATE
  SET code='Abcd';
```

For the second insert I get a unique key violation: `ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "mytable_lower_code_idx"`

(I also tried to use `ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT mytable_lower_code_idx` but Postgresql tells me that this constraint does not exist so maybe it doesn't treat the index as a constraint.)

My final question: Is there any way to make INSERT ... ON CONFLICT work together with indexes on expressions? Or must I introduce a physical indexed lowercase column to accomplish the task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ON CONFLICT (lower(code)) DO UPDATE`:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    code text
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX mytable_lower_code_idx ON mytable (lower(code));
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('abcd');

INSERT INTO mytable (code) VALUES ('Abcd')
  ON CONFLICT (lower(code)) DO UPDATE
  SET code='Abcd';

SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

yields

```
| code |
|------|
| Abcd |
```

---

Note that [`ON CONFLICT` syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)
allows for the conflict target to be an `index_expression` (my emphasis):

> `ON CONFLICT conflict_target`
>         where `conflict_target` can be one of:
>
> ```
> ( { index_column_name | ( index_expression ) } [ COLLATE collation ] [ opclass ] [, ...] ) [ WHERE index_predicate ]
>     ON CONSTRAINT constraint_name
> ```
>
> and `index_expression`:
>
> Similar to index_column_name, but **used to infer expressions on
>       table_name columns appearing within index definitions** (not simple
>       columns). Follows CREATE INDEX format.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your index as follow:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY mytable_lower_code_idx 
ON mytable (lower(code));

ALTER TABLE mytable 
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_mytab_code
UNIQUE USING INDEX mytable_lower_code_idx ;
```

and then:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (code) VALUES ('abcd');

-- second insert, with upsert behaviour
INSERT INTO mytable (code) VALUES ('Abcd')
  ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT unique_mytab_code DO UPDATE
  SET code='Abcd';
```

Comment: Thanks! - I still accepted the other answer since it did not require adding an additional constraint.